# DataTables - Adding filtering function to a column

Tags: jquery-plugins, datatables

I have a table which have information which I would like to exclude from the search box. For example, in one of the columns I have some text and then links, it looks like that:

```
<td>
  <div>John Doe</div>
  <div>
    <a href="/usr/johndoe/view">View</a> | 
    <a href="/usr/johndoe/edit">Edit</a> |
    <a href="/usr/johndoe/delete">Delete</a>
  </div>
</td>
```

Of-course in this case I would like the search box to consider only "John Doe" as a text to be searched.

I draw my table in php (I use Symfony-2) and apply the DataTable plugin using dataTable function with jQuery. I got the impression that what I want is possible, but couldn't manage to achieve it. Other discussions like http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/255/customising-the-way-the-filter-works/p1 neither helped me to solve this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to happen exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are ways to customize the actual search function (you could specify the type for the column using mDataProp and then write a [custom filter](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering) for that type maybe?).

But a different way to go about it is to have your PHP script only supply the name: John Doe.  This will be the original data for the cell.

Then in your column definitions, use `fnRender()` to format the cell using the layout you use in your question -- and have it automatically parse the name to create the links you want (assuming all names are first and last, and all links just use the combined first/last names, this should be fairly easy to implement).

Then set `bUseRendered` to `false` for that column and it will perform all of its sorting and filtering based on the original content, not the new content.  [See more here](http://datatables.net/ref#bUseRendered).

Comment: Great, thanks. One question - I need some arguments to the rendering (like userId, username etc...) - any idea how can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you just just pass something like in the example they give (`fnRender(o) { }`) then you should be able to call something like `o.aData[idx]` where `idx` is the zero-based index of the column that contains the data you want to parse.  So for example you could do something like `var content = o.aData[1] + ' <a href="/usr/' + o.aData[1].toLowerCase().replace(" ","") + '/view">View</a>';` and then `return content;`.  That would you give you `John Doe <a href="/usr/johndoe/view">View</a>` in your cell.  Does that make sense / answer your question?

Comment: Well, it doesn't because my example is not complete. Just to make it clearer, let's say that tje url should contain also user-id, which cannot be retrieved from the column since it is not shown: `<a href="/usr/372/johndoe/view">View</a>` (there are more parameters but the idea is the same).
I can generate an array with username as key and then the rest of information I need, but it is quite ugly... prefer to have a better solution, which I am sure that exists..

Comment: Pass the associated user-id or other information in their own individual columns.  Set those columns as `"bVisible": false` and `"bSearchable": false`.  This will prevent users from seeing or searching through this data.   Then in your display cell with your view, edit, etc links - still use `fnRender` but reference those other columns as well through the `aData` object.  i.e. `var content = o.aData[1] + '<a href="/usr/' + o.aData[2] + '/view">View</a>';` or something like that.